# Kentico 8.2 Media Library permissions

Tags: permissions, media, kentico

I have set up a user and assigned him to a role.  While I am able to permit or deny access to different pages in the site, assigning access restrictions in Media Library -> Security seems to have no effect.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign them to a role. Configure both '**Permissions**' and '**UI personalization**' like you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

David

Comment: Thank you, that actually narrows down the user permissions quite a bit.  However I'm still having a problem with the media library:  E.g. I have three Regions, three Roles and three Media Libraries.  I configured Role 1 to have access to Region 1, Role 2 accesses Region 2 etc., then set the permissions in the Media Library 1 to only allow access to Role 1.   When a User w/ Role1 signs into the CMS admin, they can still see and modify Media Library 2 and 3 as well.  It's as if the Media Library permissions are ignored.

I'm referring to Media Library -> Edit -> Security -> Authorized roles.

Comment: @D3v The "Manage" permission, as described in my answer, overrides the Media Library -> Security tab settings. Perhaps that was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check to make sure you do not have any global or higher level permissions set on those users that would override your specific security settings.  For instance is a user was set to a role but also has Global Admin rights, the global admin would override all the permissions.

Also have you tested if the users can actually edit those libraries? (add, edit, remove items) or can they just see the media items in there?

Comment: The user does not have either 'Global Admin' or 'Admin' rights.  He can add, edit, view or remove items from any of the media libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Disabling the "Manage" permission while leaving "Read" enabled via the Role's Permissions -> Media libraries (Module) resolved it. See my response here: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/limit-access-to-media-libraries